# How to get the total duration of media being played in PyQt4?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt4, phonon, audio-player

I am trying to write a small audio player in PyQt4. This is a part of the code I've written:

```
class Player(QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self, fileLoc, parent = None):
        super(QMainWindow, self).__init__()
        self.totTime = 0
        self.audioOutput = Phonon.AudioOutput(Phonon.MusicCategory, self)
        self.mediaObject = Phonon.MediaObject(self)

        self.mediaObject.setTickInterval(1000)

        self.mediaObject.tick.connect(self.tick)
        self.mediaObject.stateChanged.connect(self.stateChanged)

        Phonon.createPath(self.mediaObject, self.audioOutput)

        #Define Play, Pause and Stop actions
        self.playAction = QAction(self.style().standardIcon(QStyle.SP_MediaPlay),
                            "Play", self, enabled = False, triggered = self.mediaObject.play)

        self.pauseAction = QAction(self.style().standardIcon(QStyle.SP_MediaPause),
                            "Pause", self, enabled = False, triggered = self.mediaObject.pause)

        self.stopAction = QAction(self.style().standardIcon(QStyle.SP_MediaStop),
                            "Stop", self, enabled = False, triggered = self.mediaObject.stop)

        #Initiate User Interface
        self.userInterface()
        self.timeDisp.display('00:00')

        self.mediaObject.setCurrentSource(Phonon.MediaSource(fileLoc))
        self.mediaObject.play()

    def tick(self, time):
        self.displayTime = QTime(0, (time / 60000) % 60, (time / 1000) % 60)
        self.timeDisp.display(self.displayTime.toString('mm:ss'))
```

My problem is, I am unable to figure out how to get the total duration of the file being currently played. I have tried printing the output of mediObject.totalTime() at the end of **init**(). But it returned -1 for all the videos.  mediObject.totalTime() inside tick() is returning incorrect duration (10 - 15 seconds longer than the actual duration).

Also, I may have to access the value of total duration from outside the class. How can I do this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You could connect the `pause`, `play`, and `stop` actions with other functions:

in the class `__init__`:

```
self.total_time = 0
self.playing = False
self.play_action = QAction(self.style().standardIcon((QStyle.SP_MediaPlay),"play",self) 
self.play_action.triggered.connect(self.play_triggered_event)
```

and define the rest of the actions in a similar manner, `connect`ing the `triggered` field of each `QAction` to a function

```
def play_triggered_event(self):
    if not self.playing:
        self.mediaObject.play
        self.playing = True
        self.start_time = time.clock()

def pause_triggered_event(self):
    if self.playing:
        self.mediaObject.pause
        self.playing = False
        self.total_time += (time.clock() - self.start_time)

def stop_triggered_event(self):
    if self.playing:
       self.mediaObject.stop
       self.playing = False
       print "Total time elapsed: " + str(self.total_time)
```

Basically, it's about saving some program state when the actions that affect the time elapsed are triggered.

To get the total time outside of the class, write an accessor for the class:

```
def get_total_time(self):
    return self.total_time
```

Comment: That doesn't help in getting the duration of the file *currently being played*, does it?